# Is it possible to upload 30gb of data to Google Colab as the limit of drive is 15gb?

Tags: nvidia, google-colaboratory

I want to train a model on Google Colab on a 30gb dataset. However colab requires the data to be uploaded on google drive which has the free maximum capacity of 15gb. So how can I upload the data for colab to train on for free?

Answer (score 3):

This is part of the "free" limits of google colab. If you dont have paid space on drive, you cant work with big data.